# Convert minutes to hours and minutes

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

Need to change minutes to hours and minutes. Tried with lot of expressions but didn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYSMX.png)

column name : decimal days * 24 AS Flying_time

Passed below custom code in report properties and expression

Answer (score 0):

Your expression to format rev in minutes to rev in hours:minutes

```
=  Fields!rev.Value \ 60  & ":" & Right("0" &  Fields!rev.Value Mod 60 ,2)
```

And for rev summaries

```
=  SUM(Fields!rev.Value) \ 60   & ":" & Right("0" &  SUM(Fields!rev.Value) Mod 60 ,2)
```

Use similar expression for the position column.

For the total you can use an expression like

```
=Sum(Fields!rev.Value + Fields!position.Value) \ 60 & ":" & Right("0" & Sum(Fields!rev.Value + Fields!position.Value)  Mod 60,
2)
```

[image]

[image]